# HTML background is not shown in email inbox

Tags: html, css, email, ruby-on-rails-4, mailchimp

This is the code i have 
http://goo.gl/7GG8aH
Everything is working,and is sent properly but the background image just doesn't want to show up.
Looking into my snippet from codepen.io above

You will see that the background color is present 
[image: snippet background present]

but when it gets directed to my gmail inbox this is how i get it 
[image: no background]

> **Question:** How can i make the background image to appear in my actually
>   gmail inbox as it does in codepen.io snippet?

Answer (score 0):

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/145919?hl=en

It is likely that your Gmail is configured to not show images or links on html emails.

Answer (score 0):

just add background:#ccc in body tag

Answer (score 0):

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTable" bgcolor="#eeeeee">
```

just had to add `bgcolor="#eeeeee"` to the `table` methods.